# Creating a cross-account role to perform VPC associations with Private Hosted Zones

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-route53

I'm trying to create an IAM cross-account role following the example in https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role. I want a central account (7935xxxxxxxxx) to be able to create a VPC association between a VPC in a workload account (6617xxxxxxxx) to a private hosted zone in the central account. The association can only be performed as though from the workload account. But I get this error:

```
"An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssociateVPCWithHostedZone operation: User: arn:aws:sts::6617xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/AssumeFromCoreRole/cross_acct_lambda is not authorized to perform: route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone on resource: arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:6617xxxxxxxxx:vpc/vpc-0f37262673a5e9762 because no resource-based policy allows the route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone action"
```

I'm nor sure this error message is pointing me to the true problem as my understanding is that [Route 53 doesn't have resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html).

I've double-checked all my ducks are lined up:

1. The workload account has a role that allows it to assume a role from the central account:

```
DNSACrossAccountRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Sid: AssumeRole
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          'AWS': !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${CoreAccountID}:role/DNS-Automation-Factory-${Environment}'
        Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
  RoleName: AssumeFromCoreRole
```

2. The Lambda execution role in the central account allows the workload account to assume its role along with the necessary actions:

```
      DNSAutomationRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Sid: LambdaAssumeRole
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: 'lambda.amazonaws.com'
              Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          RoleName: !Sub DNS-Automation-Factory-${Environment}
          Policies:
          - PolicyName: 'work-with-private-hosted-zone'
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                - route53:CreateVPCAssociationAuthorization
                - route53:CreateHostedZone
                - route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone
                - ec2:DescribeVpcs
                Resource: '*'
              - Sid: AllowCrossAccountAccess
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
                Resource: arn:aws:iam::6617xxxxxxxxx:role/AssumeFromCoreRole
```

3. The Python client code calls STS to assume the role to execute the API call:

```
def cross_account_client():
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::6617xxxxxxxxx:role/AssumeFromCoreRole",
        RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )

    ACCESS_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    # create service client using the assumed role credentials, e.g. S3
    client = boto3.client(
        'route53',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
    )
    return client
```

Then, I use it this way:

```
r53_cross_account_role_client = cross_account_client()
    try:
        logger.info('Calling associate_vpc_with_hosted_zone')
        r53_cross_account_role_client.associate_vpc_with_hosted_zone(
            HostedZoneId=phz_id,
            VPC={
                'VPCRegion': aws_region,
                'VPCId': workload_vpc_id
            }
        )
```

But I must be missing something obvious. Has anyone else come across the same?

Comment: Looking at the error message, AssumeFromCoreRole is being used to authenticate the route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone operation.  You show a function that looks valid to create a client with the assumed credentials, but do you call that function?  Do you use the client from it?

Comment: I've updated the original question with how I'm using the assumed credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this correctly, I think you have reverse relation between roles. Specifically, you mentioned that you want workload account to assume role in central account, but then your workload role is defined as:

```
DNSACrossAccountRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Sid: AssumeRole
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          'AWS': !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${CoreAccountID}:role/DNS-Automation-Factory-${Environment}'
        Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
  RoleName: AssumeFromCoreRole
```

Which does the opposite - it allows core account to assume it, not the other way around. If you want your workload role to be able to assume core account you need to use `Policies`, not `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`. As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-assumerolepolicydocument), `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` specified who can assume this role.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain the dilemma adequately, and I've updated the question. The central account needs to perform a VPC association between a VPC in the workload account and a private hosted zone in the central account. And, the only way this can be done is as though from the workload account.